# Scaling my Kinesis consumers when consumption is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, producer-consumer

Assume I have a AWS Kinesis stream with 2 shards.
Therefore I have two consumers consuming from each shard.

There are large number of entries in the queues and my consumer is consuming it slowly.
To solve this I can go with Kafka consumer group like approach ,create two consumer applications and consume records.

But I want to know whether I can Reshard my queue (which will distribute the records across shards) and add consumers for that shards.
i.e After resharding my stream will have 4 shards and hence 4 consumers.
This will also increase the consumption and solve my problem.

Whats the pros and cons of the second approach as the second approach is generally suggested when the queue has ingestion issue?

Comment: Will frequent resharding have issue with the overall performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding shards to increase consuming capacity is exactly what kinesis is about. It will increase the parallelism of your "consumer application" and should be pretty seamless.

Note that aws recently introduced a serverless kinesis model where you don't have to care about the shard count anymore. It's pretty much equivalent to letting `aws` care about the number of shards by itself so you don't have to worry about that anymore.